# Object or Provider is not able to perform the requested operation

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, odbc, oledb, rds

I am trying to run the classic asp application which uses RDS ([Remote data service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676188(v=vs.85).aspx)) on Windows Server 2008

```
<object id="RDS_ACCOUNTS" CLASSID="clsid:BD96C556-65A3-11D0-983A-00C04FC29E33"
 height=1 width=1 VIEWASTEXT>
```

Following is the code written in window_load() event

```
RDS_ACCOUNTS.ExecuteOptions = 1
RDS_ACCOUNTS.FetchOptions = 1
RDS_ACCOUNTS.Server = "<%=strServer%>"
RDS_ACCOUNTS.Connect =Connect
RDS_ACCOUNTS.SQL = "SELECT ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID, CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESC 
   FROM TBL_AP_CHART_ACCOUNT_TYPE 
   WHERE CLIENT_ID=<% = Session("ClientID")%> 
   ORDER BY ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESC "
RDS_ACCOUNTS.Refresh
Dim AccountRst
Set AccountRst = RDS_ACCOUNTS.Recordset
```

Here connect variable have its value from RDSConn.inc file which have the value

```
Handler=MSDFMAP.Handler;Data Source=AMTAPP;
```

This handler picks value from msdfmap.ini file located in `C:\Windows` folder which contains the `OLEDB Connection String`or DSN Name.
But when i run this code it gives me exception

> **Object or Provider is not able to perform the requested operation** on **RDS_ACCOUNTS.Refresh** method.

Comment: Visit this link, it may help: https://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/access-database-errors.htm

Comment: Don't  Get the Answer..@BhupendraShukla

Comment: Could be a permissions issue? Does the user that the website runs under have RDS permissions?

Comment: Yes the user have the permission to run the RDS

Comment: Why this question has tag 'vba'?

Comment: Does it work properly if you set the `RDS_ACCOUNTS.Connect` directly equal to the OLEDB string, rather than using `MSDFMAP.Handler`?

Comment: No it does not work properly @transistor1

Comment: where do `strServer` and `Session("ClientID")` come from?

Comment: it comes from the application and this page is the part of that application. you can use "http://url" in the place of "<%=strServer%> and on the place of whole sql query you can write any simple select query.

Comment: but should it be `RDS_ACCOUNTS.Server = strServer` not `RDS_ACCOUNTS.Server = "<%=strServer%>"`?

Comment: Does a more trivial request work ? (i.e. playing with constant values)

Comment: But it works on different server...@oraclecertifiedprofessional

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional No the OP is passing the `<%= strServer %>` as a server-side variable to the `RDS_ACCOUNTS.Server` which is running in client side VBScript.

Comment: Is this VBS file or Classic ASP?

Comment: Almost feels like this is what the code should look like


RDS_ACCOUNTS.ExecuteOptions = 1
RDS_ACCOUNTS.FetchOptions = 1
RDS_ACCOUNTS.Server = strServer
RDS_ACCOUNTS.Connect =Connect
RDS_ACCOUNTS.SQL = "SELECT ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID, CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESC 
   FROM TBL_AP_CHART_ACCOUNT_TYPE 
   WHERE CLIENT_ID=" & Session("ClientID") & "
   ORDER BY ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESC "
RDS_ACCOUNTS.Refresh
Dim AccountRst
Set AccountRst = RDS_ACCOUNTS.Recordset